# Golang Api Only Matches Last Route

Tags: api, go, mux

I have a golang api application. I've defined a set of routes and handlers. However, the mux router only ever returns the last route.

When I request `/api/info` I get this in my logging:

`9:0:38 app | 2018/02/05 09:00:38 GET /api/info Users Create 308.132µs`

Why is that routing to the wrong route?

routing package:

```
// NewRouter establishes the root application router
func NewRouter(context *config.ApplicationContext, routes Routes, notFoundHandler http.HandlerFunc) *mux.Router {
    router := mux.NewRouter()

    router.NotFoundHandler = notFoundHandler

    for _, route := range routes {
        router.
            PathPrefix("/api").
            Methods(route.Method).
            Path(route.Pattern).
            Name(route.Name).
            // TODO: fix HandlerFunc. Right now, it is overriding previous routes and setting a single handler for all
            // this means that the last route is the only router with a handler
            HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
                logRoute(setJSONHeader(route.HandlerFunc), route.Name)(context, w, r)
            })

    }

    return router
}

func logRoute(inner ContextHandlerFunc, name string) ContextHandlerFunc {
    return func(c *config.ApplicationContext, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        start := time.Now()

        inner(c, w, r)

        log.Printf(
            "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s",
            r.Method,
            r.RequestURI,
            name,
            time.Since(start),
        )
    }
}

func setJSONHeader(inner ContextHandlerFunc) ContextHandlerFunc {
    return func(c *config.ApplicationContext, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        inner(c, w, r)
    }
}
```

main package:

```
var context = config.ApplicationContext{
    Database: database.NewDatabase().Store,
}

var routes = router.Routes{
    router.Route{"Info", "GET", "/info", handlers.InfoShow},
    router.Route{"Users Create", "POST", "/users/create", handlers.UsersCreate},
}

func main() {    
    notFoundHandler := handlers.Errors404
    router := router.NewRouter(&context, routes, notFoundHandler)

    port := os.Getenv("PORT")

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":"+port, router))
}
```

If I visit `/api/info` it will attempt to call a POST to `/users/create`.  However, if I remove the second route, it will correctly route to the `InfoShow` handler.

Why is mux overriding the first route?  I'm fairly certain there's something wrong with

```
HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    logRoute(setJSONHeader(route.HandlerFunc), route.Name)(context, w, r)
})
```

but I'm not sure why that would cause it to map over the first route.

Ideas?

Comment: Please clarify what `mux` package you are using.

Comment: @leafbebop I'm using the latest of https://github.com/gorilla/mux

Comment: Unrelated, but this is terrible practice: `router := router.NewRouter(&context, routes, notFoundHandler)`.  You're shadowing the `router` package with the `router` variable.  Name them differently.  As a matter of practice, it's recommended to _not_ name your packages after what someone would naturally name the type from that package.  Instead of router, use the `routing` name you specified in the OP.  Will make for less confusing code.

Comment: Thanks.  New to golang. That was unintentional and I'll rename it. The whole point of what I'm trying to do is passing the database into the handlers.  Go is forcing me to separate everything into packages but fundamentally, the pieces are a single package so I'm having a hard time finding a good structure.

Comment: You _can_ put them all in the same package, if you want.  Separating them can be good practice, as it lets you isolate concerns better, but there's nothing in Go that _forces_ you to separate code into packages, unless you want to have the documentation benefits of separate namespaces.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to put them in separate packages but you need to have a very good understanding of application structure before you begin which is good but it's definitely a challenge.  I didn't image that sharing a db connection downstream to handlers would be this challenging.  One thing I miss from my background in Rails is a canonical structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading through your code and gorilla/mux, I think I know the issue.  You're using the for loop variable `route`, and specifically its field HanderFunc, in the function literal, but because of how function literals work, the *value* of that field is not evaluated until the that function literal is called.  In Go, the second variable in a range loop is *reused* on each iteration, rather than created anew, and so after the for loop, if it's still in scope of anything (like your function literal), it will contain the value of the *last* loop iteration.  Here's an example of what I mean:

https://play.golang.org/p/Xx62tuwhtgG

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var funcs []func()
    ints := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

    // How you're doing it
    for i, a := range ints {
        fmt.Printf("Loop i: %v, a: %v\n", i, a)
        funcs = append(funcs, func() {
            fmt.Printf("Lambda i: %v, a: %v\n", i, a)
        })
    }

    for _, f := range funcs {
        f()
    }

    fmt.Println("-------------")

    // How you *should* do it
    funcs = nil
    for i, a := range ints {
        i := i
        a := a
        fmt.Printf("Loop i: %v, a: %v\n", i, a)
        funcs = append(funcs, func() {
            fmt.Printf("Lambda i: %v, a: %v\n", i, a)
        })
    }

    for _, f := range funcs {
        f()
    }
}
```

In the first example, `i` and `a` are being reused on each loop iteration, and aren't evaluated for their values in the lambda (function literal) until that lambda is actually *called* (by the `funcs` loop).  To fix that, you can shadow `a` and `i` by redeclaring them *inside* the scope of the loop iteration (but outside the lambda's scope).  This makes a separate copy for each iteration, to avoid issues with reuse of the same variable.

Specifically for your code, if you change your code to the following, it should work:

```
for _, route := range routes {
    route := route // make a copy of the route for use in the lambda
    // or alternatively, make scoped vars for the name and handler func

    router.
        PathPrefix("/api").
        Methods(route.Method).
        Path(route.Pattern).
        Name(route.Name).
        // TODO: fix HandlerFunc. Right now, it is overriding previous routes and setting a single handler for all
        // this means that the last route is the only router with a handler
        HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            logRoute(setJSONHeader(route.HandlerFunc), route.Name)(context, w, r)
        })
}
```

Comment: Ahh that makes so much sense!  Thanks for the example.  I will test this out later but based upon your playground I think this is absolutely right.  I'm wondering if this pattern I have of setting a bunch of routes iteratively is actually a good approach.

Comment: I've seen worse.  It allows you to specify your routes in `main` while actually handling attaching them to the router in your routing package.  That's good design, because there's no real reason your routing package should be the one managing your route associations.

Comment: This is also a pretty common problem in JavaScript when you're creating a bunch of callback function closures in a loop. Looks like the same solutions apply in Go: use another function (named or anonymous) to build the callback function and force the loop variables to be evaluated rather than closed over.

Comment: Yep, you could move the entire piece inside the loop into another named function that accepts the `router` (as a pointer) and the `route` (as a struct), and simply call that function inside the loop.  Since the `route` argument would be being passed as a value, it would automagically be copied and the reuse issues would disappear.